# Can std::chrono::system_clock::now() throw an exception?

Tags: c++, c++11, portability, language-lawyer, c++-chrono

I want to write a very portable code, and I need to call `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` in the initialization. Can this function throw an exception ?

In c++11 standard, there is no mention of that issue. (At least, I didn't found one)

In Visual Studio, the sourcecode is as follow :

```
static time_point now() _NOEXCEPT
    {   // get current time
    return (time_point(duration(_Xtime_get_ticks())));
    }
```

With the _NOEXCEPT keyword, the answer in visual studio is pretty obvious. But what about the general case ?

Comment: Just a note: `_NOEXCEPT` is not a keyword. It's an implementation-specific macro that expands to the keyword `noexcept` for compilers that support it and to nothing for compilers that don't.

Comment: @PeteBecker of course

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can this function throw an exception ?

**No**, it cannot.

Per paragraph 20.11.7/1 of the C++11 Standard, `system_clock` must satisfy the `TrivialClock` requirements.

Moreover, per paragraph 20.11.3/4, the `now()` member function of clocks that satisfy the `TrivialClock` requirement shall not throw:

> A type `TC` meets the `TrivialClock` requirements if:
>
> [...]
>
> — **the function `TC::now()` does not throw exceptions**, and
>
> [...]

Answer (score 12):

From §20.11.7.1

```
class system_clock {
public:
  ...
    static time_point now() noexcept;  
  ...
};
```

So the standard states it cannot throw an exception.

Comment: Do you have the final C++11 standard ? I only have the latest draft and in 20.11.7.1 I only have this : static time_point now();

Comment: @Arnaud: AFAIK the latest draft is n3485, and the `noexcept` is there

Comment: @AndyProwl Thank you so much ! I was not aware that I was using a very old draft. I really thought I downloaded the latest.

Comment: @AndyProwl IMHO n3485 is a draft for the next standard. I am now using n3337 (which is also a draft for next standard but based on the current standard with only typo correction) instead of n3242 (which was old and missing most of the noexcept keywords)